# System.out.println in Tomcat and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I am running Tomcat inside Eclipse. Is there any harm in using System.out.println only during development to see some output on the Eclipse console for testing? I know I have heard that this is bad practice, but I can't remember why. I don't need anything fancy like log4j for this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call log4j particularly complex. In particular, there's a *lot* of information out there about using it in Tomcat, and it's useful to be able to use the same logging infrastructure during development and later when you actually deploy your code.

In terms of using `System.out.println` - I doubt that it'll do any really significant harm, but I wouldn't expect as much effort to have been put into making `System.out` output efficient in Tomcat as logging in log4j. It's also a lot less flexible - you're more likely to end up adding and removing logging in your code because you can't easily do it via configuration.

In other words: while it's probably not too bad to use `System.out.println`, I think it would be worth investing the relatively small amount of time required to use a more flexible logging solution (whether that's log4j or something else). It's a one-off hit with an ongoing benefit.

Comment: One of the reasons I don't want to use a logging infrastructure for this app is that it will be deployed on Elastic Beanstalk, which runs the app on multiple instances. My logging will probably end up in a table in Amazon RDS :)

Comment: @Ralph: That doesn't mean you shouldn't use any logging infrastructure - it just means you should use some which has support for Elastic Beanstalk. Ultimately you still don't want to have to change your *code* between development and deployment to account for changes to logging - you want to just reconfigure it to write to the most appropriate place.

Comment: Thank you so much. I own your book, by the way.

Comment: @Ralph: So what are you doing writing Java? ;) (Just kidding - I'm only an *amateur* in C# myself, sad to say. Java is the day job.)

Comment: I am planning on having a simple table with date/time and message columns which I would write to directly from the app. Actually, that same code can probably run in the dev environment too, if I identify where the message is coming from.

Comment: @Ralph: Right. It may be worth seeing if someone else has already done this in an open source project - logging is obviously going to be a pretty common requirement.

Comment: And if not, I should do it :) You can't fool me into thinking you're an amatuer in C#. I told you, I have read your book! It is awesome.

Comment: @Ralph: But I'm not a *professional* C# developer - I don't get paid for C# development. That makes me an amateur... just a rather keen one :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can use it. Note, that sometimes `Eclipse` browser differs from outside browsers and `System.out.println` prints different(mainly it concerns the paths). 
Just not use `Eclispe` browser

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any harm other than the very simple probability of forgetting and leaving it there.  Thus eventually leaving logs files unnecessarily verbose.  At the very least, perhaps use System.err instead of out so you can keep normal output clean.

Comment: Actually, for some reason, in the default configuration of Eclipse and Tomcat, all the Tomcat messages are for some reason redirected to System.err and show up in red. The System.out stands out because it is black!

Answer (score 1):

Logging frameworks have logging levels, can redirect logging messages to appropriate log books, structured logging, plus you could neatly format the logs etc. Using System.out.println simple dumps it on the console, so if your application logs trace messages along with errors while development, you would have your entire console filled up, literally making it untraceble.

If you are doing serious application development you should use a logging framework during development. And incase you werent convinced by my thoughts, yet [GIYF](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=java+why+to+use+a+logging+framework).

Comment: The app I am working on will run on Elastic Beanstalk on multiple server instances. The logging system I eventually implement will have to write to a cloud database like Amazon RDS.

Comment: My bad! Just struck me why you were trying to use console for logging. Personally I've never configured a log on a cloud, but I think this [link](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/index.html?using-features.loggingS3.title.html) shows how to configure the log framework using Beanstalk. As far as development is concerned, I still think its good to use a log framework, particularly for log redirection & tracebility.

Comment: I agree. I have used java.util.logging before and that's what Amazon uses on the beanstalk instances. But the logs are separate for each instance.